# Route issue in Laravel 5.7.2

Tags: laravel-5.6, laravel-5.7

I have just downloaded Laravel 5.7.2 project and found an issue below.

**Below line does not work in Laravel 5.7.2 and gives 404**

```
Route::get('/login', 
    array(
        'uses' =>  'Annonymous\Web\Auth\Login\LoginController@showLoginForm', 
        'as'   =>  'showLoginForm'
    )
);
```

**Below works in Laravel 5.7.2**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('Annonymous.welcome');
});
```

**Below code works in Laravel 5.6.16 and 5.6.33**

```
Route::get('/login', 
    array(
        'uses' =>  'Annonymous\Web\Auth\Login\LoginController@showLoginForm', 
        'as'   =>  'showLoginForm'
    )
);
```

Any idea why the same code does not work in 5.7.2 ?

I can confirm that the route is present in the route list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since your project is not in root of Localhost 
Try 'php artisan serve'
It Will Work

Comment: I already tried that  and also removed my route to make sure the existing route work. But, still same problem.

Comment: Send the screenshot